# MySQL Database starts on Terminal But not on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I am trying to start MySQL Database on XAMPP, and it doesn't start.
But when I ran this on my terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

The terminal gives me a success message.
How can I check if MySQL Database is actually running?
And how can I make the status on XAMPP say Running and not Stopped?

Thank you!

But when I ran this on my terminal:

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

The terminal gives me a success message.

How can I check if MySQL Database is actually running?

And how can I make the status on XAMPP say Running and not Stopped?

Thank you!

Comment: don't know if any of my answer in this [Very persistent /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process. Xampp/ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511277/very-persistent-opt-lampp-bin-mysql-server-264-kill-no-such-process-xampp-u/60371785#60371785) post would help you solve this xampp problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this command:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Comment: Thank you! The database was running. The software just wasn't showing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use one of the commands to check mysql running on Linux.**

1. mysqladmin -u root -p status

   if mysql running it will display output uptime and queries else you get failed error
2. sudo service mysqld status   OR    # /etc/init.d/mysqld status

   For Ubuntu use **service mysql status**