# XAMPP and Docker conflict (MySQL)

Tags: macos, docker, xampp, mariadb

So I've been used to developing websites via XAMPP before uploading to a VPS later on. But through my new work, I've been set up with Docker. I still develop in XAMPP for one client, and in Docker for another client. I'm on a Macintosh.

The issue is with MySQL after installing Docker. Before installing, MySQL ran fine. After installing, it never starts, even after a fresh reboot. Only Docker can start MySQL now. And no, I'm not trying to run two instances of MySQL at the same time. When I try to start MySQL via XAMP, I do not have MySQL open in Docker (I stop MySQL in Docker and reboot my computer, and still XAMPP won't start MySQL).

Has anyone run into a similar problem?

---

Running MySQL from the Mac Terminal like this:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Yields this:

```
Starting MariaDB
.2020-08-24 11:46:18 4493 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MBP-2012.err'.
2020-08-24 11:46:18 4493 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (4493) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

---

```
ps auxww|grep mysqld
```

Yields:

```
Matt              6334   0.0  0.0  4258892    220 s001  R+   12:48PM   0:00.00 grep mysqld
```

Comment: Is this your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60371785/14048240

Comment: I just read this one before posting, I couldn't seem to get mine working…

Comment: for such purposes you need to show the myswl error log, if the process didn't start there will you see what the problem is

Comment: Check your bin directory if `mysqld_safe` exists. If yes try to run it manually. `cd mysql_installation_directory` and then `bin/mysqld_safe &`

Comment: @nbk Have I done the correct thing to read the error log? `ps auxww|grep mysqld`

Comment: @majidhajibaba `mysqld_safe` does exist. Running it yields the following three lines: `[1] 6760`, `zsh: command not found: mysql_safe` and `[1]  + exit 127   mysql_safe`

Comment: **Maybe** your installation was incomplete if `mysqld_safe.sh`  file does not exist. Try to reinstall and check any warning during installation. Open */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server* and see line 264 to see it tries to run mysqld_safe or mysqld? Try to run it by recommended arguments in the script.

Comment: As I said, It _does_ exist. It just doesn't recognise it as a command. EDIT: Opened the wrong file in Sublime. I'm reading it now.

Comment: Line 264 says: `log_error "WSREP: Failed to recover position: 'cat $wr_logfile'"`

Comment: Do you truly need Galera cluster in your dev configuration?

Comment: I have no idea what that is…

Comment: Solved the issue! -- I will post my solution within a day or so. It has to do with the fact that the default memory capacity of output buffers (i.e. `ob_start(); echo $something; $content = ob_get_clean();`) only can store up to 4MB at one time. I managed to change this range, and my site runs fine now. -- Again, I'll post a detailed answer for other people very soon!

Comment: Omg, I posted the above comment on a wrong question lol… I meant that I solved another question … ugh. This one still needs an answer!

Answer (score 0):

what about try to use [Devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)

> xampp/wamp based on docker